# Conditions in my if statement on the js file is being ignored although I've changed the variable forcibly at the end of the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("calculatorApp", []);

app.controller("CalculatorCtrl", CalculatorCtrl);

function CalculatorCtrl() {
    pleaseWork = null;
    this.buttonClicked = function(button) {
        if (pleaseWork = null)
        {
            this.secondNumber = button;
            pleaseWork = "I don't know why this won't work."
        } else {
            this.firstNumber = button;
        }
    }
    this.opButtonClicked = function(opButton) {
        this.operationType = opButton;
    }
    this.equalButtonClicked = function() {
        var firstNumber= parseFloat(this.firstNumber);
        var secondNumber= parseFloat(this.secondNumber);
        if (operationType === '+') {
            this.equalButtonClicked = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        }
        if (operationType === '-') {
            this.equalButtonClicked = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        }
        if (operationType === '*') {
            this.equalButtonClicked = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        }
        if (operationType === '/') {
            this.equalButtonClicked = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        }
    }
}
<html ng-app="calculatorApp">
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Midterm Calculator</h1>
        <div ng-controller = "CalculatorCtrl as ctrl">
            <p>
                <span ng-bind="ctrl.firstNumber"></span>
                <span ng-bind="ctrl.operationType"></span>
                <span ng-bind="ctrl.secondNumber"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" value="{{solution}}" readonly/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('1')">1</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('2')">2</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('3')">3</button>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('4')">4</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('5')">5</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('6')">6</button>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('7')">7</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('8')">8</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('9')">9</button>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('0')" >0</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.equalButtonClicked()">=</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.opButtonClicked('+')">+</button>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.opButtonClicked('-')">-</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.opButtonClicked('*')">*</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.opButtonClicked('/')">/</button>
            </p>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is within the JavaScript if function between the first and second number. For some reason unknown to me, the variable I have placed (I did not have it there before but I thought this would fix the problem) resists to be read. It always reads it as if the pleaseWork isn't null even though I specifically set it so that it is. It's probably something with Angular or JS that I've never had to deal with until now but I've been fairly frustrated since most of the things I look up about this topic regarding angular give me the ngifelse statements that I don't really want to try just yet.

Comment: `if (pleaseWork = null)`  Null is always falsy in JS, and this is assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the if condition, you need to do a comparison instead of assignment

```
if (pleaseWork == null)
```

Comment: If the question is due to a typographical error, it should be voted closed.